# PHP If test logic

Tags: php

I have a simple HTML form and one of the input fields is the 'Date From'. On the page that processes this form submission I want check that the user has entered the Date From and that it is not empty. I'm currently testing  for this:

```
if (!isset($_GET['dateFrom']) and $_GET['dateFrom'] !=='') { 
// No Date From
 $actionError = 'No Date From Entered - please go back and enter the Date From';
}
```

Just wanted to confirm that this is the correct syntax/logic to check that a user has submitted a form field input that is not empty?

Comment: The logic is wrong. You're currently checking to see if the param is _not_ set and _not_ empty. It can't be non-empty if it isn't set. You can also change it to: `if (empty($_GET['dateFrom'])) { ... }`

Comment: It would be better to to validation in the software rather than on the server, yes yes?

Comment: @BooberBunz - You should _always_ validate data on the server. You should _never_ trust user inputs even if you do have client side validation.

Comment: Well I'm just noticing how it returns an error that looks as if it's designed for the user to read and respond to: "please go back..." ... that sort of thing should take place in the app... so you don't waste bandwidth sending nonsense to the server.  But yes, the server should "validate" everything to prevent hacking, etc. and just return "FU."

Comment: @BooberBunz - And if the user has JavaScript turned off in the browser? Should they then get a "FU" instead of a proper error message? That's kind of rude, no? :-o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, if `$_GET["dateFrom"]` is not set, you shouldn't try to read the value of `$_GET["dateFrom"]`, and second, it may be better to use `&&` instead of `and` because `&&` will check the first condition, and doesn't try to evaluate the second when first evaluates to `false`. Because whatever comes after, the condition of the block will be `false` while any of it is false.

You can use this:

```
if(isset($_GET["dateFrom"]) && trim($_GET["dateFrom"]) !== "")
{
    // do things related to $_GET["dateFrom"]
}else{
    $actionError = 'No Date From Entered - please go back and enter the Date From';
}
```

Or, if you only want the negative scenario, the logic is like this:

```
!(A & B) = !A || !B
```

So,

```
if(!isset($_GET["dateFrom"]) || trim($_GET["dateFrom"]) == "")
{    
    $actionError = 'No Date From Entered - please go back and enter the Date From';
}
```

The `||` operator will continue to the second if the first is `false`. If the first condition is true, it doesn't check the latter end enter the block.

Answer (score 1):

> Just wanted to confirm that this is the correct syntax/logic to check that a user has submitted a form field input that is not empty?

As pointed out in the comments `!isset($_GET['dateFrom']) and $_GET['dateFrom'] !==''` is wrong to begin with.

`isset($_GET['dateFrom']) && $_GET['dateFrom'] !== ''` would be correct.

However ... the answer depends on your definition of "empty":

If you consider `' '` as not empty, then yes.

If you consider `' '` to be empty as well, then you need some additional input trimming (`trim` for example).

Comment: The OP asks about the logic of the if-statement, which is flawed before that check.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thanks, I didn't catch that.

Answer (score 0):

Add trim function that "`Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the beginning and end of a string`" to be sure that the field does not contains just empty spaces.

```
if (
    !isset($_GET['dateFrom'])
    || trim($_GET['dateFrom']) !== ''
) {
    $actionError = 'No Date From Entered - please go back and enter the Date From';
}
```

If you `$_GET['dataForm']` directly without `isset` you'll get an error like this:

```
Notice: Undefined index: dateFrom in php shell code on line 1
```

But if you prefer, you can replace `!isset($var) || $var == false` statement with empty($var).

> No warning is generated if the variable does not exist. That means empty() is essentially the concise equivalent to !isset($var) || $var == false.

The correct syntax logic is

```
if (empty($_GET['dateFrom'])) {
    $actionError = 'No Date ...';
}
```

Comment: If you get `$_GET['dateFrom']` and is not set you got php error. You shouldnt get a content of an array that does not exists.

Comment: refresh the browser: now logic is "if not send or empty"

Comment: I would probably just have done a `if (empty($_GET['dateFrom']))` instead, but this does it as well.

Comment: Yes, maybe due to an old habit I still continue with isset. But empty is a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple you can use `empty` .
Example :

```
if(empty($_GET["dateFrom"]))
{    
    $actionError = 'No Date From Entered - please go back and enter the Date From';
}
```

Above soulution will improve execution performance and code simplicity also.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson : Thanks for +ve comment, code is now corrected. please check now